# Getting the selected file and using IVsSingleFileGenerator

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, vsix, vs-extensibility

I am trying to add several new functions to a package I developed for our company. One of these functions is to create a new file based on the file selected in the solution explorer and the menu option selected. I have created my dynamic menu items that are on the solution explorer and it looks like I need to use [IVsSingleFileGenerator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb169282.aspx) as shown in [this sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/SingleFileGenerator).

The trouble I am having is getting the file I have selected and either reading it or passing it into a single file generator. 
I would rather generate the file from this context menu than from a custom tool action

Looks like this will get me the path of the file

```
UIHierarchy solutionExplorer = _applicationObject.ToolWindows.SolutionExplorer;

          var items = solutionExplorer.SelectedItems as Array;

          if (items == null || items.Length != 2)

          {

            return;

          }

          String strFile1 = String.Empty;

          UIHierarchyItem item1 = items.GetValue(0) as UIHierarchyItem;

          foreach (UIHierarchyItem hierarchyItem in items)

          {

            ProjectItem prjItem = hierarchyItem.Object as ProjectItem;

            string prjPath = prjItem.Properties.Item("FullPath").Value.ToString();

          }
```

which I can then use to pass into the generate function of the ivs single file generator.

Is this the best approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also posted this question to the msdn forums at:
[VSX getting the selected file and using IVsSingleFileGenerator](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsx/thread/3d194bc9-16fd-462c-be5d-6b355be90200)

I ended up using the [IPyIntegration](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/IPyIntegration) sample to figure out what i needed to do.