# How to trigger an event when I right-click a file in Visual Studio Solution Explorer?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions, vsix

I am building a Visual Studio extension (VSIX) in C# that includes custom menu commands placed in the context menu of files in the Solution Explorer.

I want to enable or disable the visibility of my menu commands based on the file path. So, when the user right-clicks a file (e.g., .cs file) in the Solution Explorer, I want an event to be triggered to change the visibility of my menu commands before the context menu is displayed.

Is there an event available for achieving this functionality?"

I tried subscribing my command class to BeforeQueryStatus event but it gets triggered only when menu command's are clicked not before it is displayed

Comment: How did you register your command in your VSCT file? Did you mark it as [DynamicVisibility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/command-flag-element?view=vs-2022)

Comment: But generally, we wouldn't expect you to be hooking the menu display to change -- instead just responding to QueryStatus would be the right thing. But we need more details to figure out what's up here.

Comment: does this helps: https://github.com/ezEngine/ezEngine/blob/e50526d31cf0b70992fa2abc5da41c5e246acc43/Utilities/UnityCtrlF7/UnityCtrlF7/Commands/CompileUnityFile_CodeWindow.cs#L35 If possible, please share some code.

Comment: Hi, here's a similar ticket: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76076746/vsix-context-menu-for-file-type/76106933#76106933